# How to show circular progress pie chart using the highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to achieve something like this.

[image]

this is what I have so far:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market share, January, 2018'
    },
            subtitle: {
                text: `<div>80%</div> of Total`,
                align: "center",
                verticalAlign: "middle",
                style: {
                  "fontSize": "7px",
                  "textAlign": "center"
                },
                x: 0,
                y: -2,
                useHTML: true
              },
    plotOptions: {
                   pie: {
                  shadow: false,
                  center: ["50%", "50%"],
                  dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                  },
                  states: {
                    hover: {
                      enabled: false
                    }
                  },
                  size: "45%",
                  innerSize: "95%",
                  borderColor: null,
                  borderWidth: 8
                }

    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    series: [{
          y: 80,


          color: {
            linearGradient: {
              x1: 0,
              x2: 0,
              y1: 0,
              y2: 1
            },
            stops: [
              [0, "#000"],
              [1, "#b0bfc6"]
            ]
          },
          name: "Speed"
        },
        {
          y: 20,
          color: "#000",
          name: "Non Prioritised"
        }],
});
```

here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gm8krq9L/

however I'm not able to get the different colors to show the progress effect on the chart. I see that there is a type called: `chart: solidgauge`, however my app does not support as I'll have to include the solidgauge file to load this kind of chart. Is there a way I can achieve this with chart type as pie?

thanks

Comment: afaik you can have changing colors depending on value only on the solidgauge type, by defining ranges and colors. One idea would be to alter the chart object externally, depending on the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a **donut** chart. I already made an example for a such chart, is it something like [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/maximelafarie/8k6rd0mz/) you want?

Anyway, [**here's a working example with your fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/maximelafarie/20paqbzh/5/).

The data is like the one you used:

```js
  series: [{
    innerSize: '80%',
    data: [{
      name: 'Speed',
      y: 80,
      color: '#e7eaeb'
    }, {
      name: 'Non Prioritised',
      y: 20,
    }]
  }],
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create that type of chart by using `pie` series type, for example:

```
series: [{
  type: 'pie',
  enableMouseTracking: false,
  innerSize: '80%',
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  data: [{
    y: 10
  }, {
    y: 90,
    color: '#e3e3e3'
  }]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4791/

**API Refernece:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.innerSize